# What does "... ..." mean over chats or posts?

Tags: american-english, ellipses

I wonder in a text what does "... ..." mean? For example, someone comments "... ..." on a picture. I tried looking at Urban Dictionary, but it didn't work.

Comment: Ellipses? If not, you'll need to provide more context.

Comment: for example in a picture then someone comment  ... ...

Answer (score 1):

Those sets of three dots following a sentence are called *ellipses*. You can certainly find its meaning in the Urban Dictionary:
https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ellipsis

It can indicate a few possible meanings, but in the case of text messages, it is generally used to indicate a break in thought or represent what would be a *pause* in spoken discourse.

Example: *“There's something I need to tell you…”.*

When you see that in chats, it may signal that more is to come, for instance when people break up longer turns in chat they can indicate a ‘trailing away’ at the end of a turn or a sentence. Say for instance *"Yeah, I guess..."*

An ellipsis can also indicate hesitation, though in this case the punctuation is more accurately described as suspension points.

*I wasn’t really... well, what I mean... see, the thing is ... I didn’t mean it.*

I hope that helps!

Reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis#On_the_Internet_and_in_text_messaging